# Mysql error saying "an expression was expected near FROM"

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT users.name,
phone_info.phone_num,
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_info
ON users.user_id = phone_info.user_id
```

I have 2 tables in my db `users` and `phone_info`. I want to use left join to execute the users who have numbers. However I get an error like this

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "FROM" at position 43)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT users.name, phone_info.phone_num, FROM users LEFT JOIN phone_info ON 
users.user_id = phone_info.user_id

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM users LEFT JOIN phone_info
ON users.user_id = phone_info.user_id' at line 3
```

Comment: get rid of the extra comma before FROM

Comment: When it tells you check "for the right syntax to use near..." the problem is generally the very last thing *before* that point.  Since that thing *by itself* was valid syntax, but then the next thing you tried to do wasn't valid in that context.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the extra comma before FROM

```
SELECT users.name,
phone_info.phone_num
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_info
ON users.user_id = phone_info.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The error explains it self.

```
An expression was expected. (near "FROM" at position 43);
```

Because you have entered a comma(`,`) MySQL expects an expression after that. Just remove it.

Here's the query;

```
SELECT users.name,
phone_info.phone_num
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_info
ON users.user_id = phone_info.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT users.name,
phone_info.phone_num
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_info
ON users.user_id = phone_info.user_id ;`I just removed that extra comma .try now I should work